# Magmi cannot create directory for product images

Tags: magento-1, import, image, magmi

I am trying to import products using magmi. But it cannot create directories to copy images. I am getting this error.

> Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error creating
>   media/catalog/product/f/a: 2,mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission
>   denied

The directory   media/catalog/product/ has 777 permissions but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Tasawer, can you give us the exact error that you're receiving? It is likely to be a permission error. Using 777 probably will solve the problem, but there will be a more precise answer.

Comment: @james question edited

Comment: do the subdirectories exist and do they have the same owner/permissions as the `catalog/product` directory?

Comment: all available sub categories have 777 permissions, but looks like magmi is creating some as well.

Comment: How did you solve it exactly? Can you list the steps? I can't seem to get it to work. I'm having the same issues.

Comment: On magmi main page there is a option "Filesystem Path to magento directory:" I set its value to "../../"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by putting

> Filesystem Path to magento directory: ../../

Comment: Hello, I got same issue.. Can I know more details your solution? Where should I put the line you mention? can I know example if my domain is 'mydomain.com?

Comment: In global Magmi settings you can set Magento path